# How to implement function with one argument that swaps private content of objects

Tags: c++, function, class, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I have created a class which stores a private expression tree. I have to add a function to this class which takes its own type as an argument and swaps the trees of these objects. If I could use 2 arguments I suppose I could create a friend function. I would appreciate some ideas as to how I could go about implementing such a function.

Comment: Are you talking about a member function? Like `MyClass::swapTrees(MyClass& other)`

Comment: Yes. I suppose I need some help-functions.

Comment: You could probably use `std::swap`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a demonstrative program that shows how a member function swap can be defined.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

class A
{
private:
    int x;
public:
    explicit A( int x = 0 ) : x( x ) {}

    void swap( A &a ) noexcept
    {
        int tmp = std::move( a.x );
        a.x = std::move( this->x );
        this->x = std::move( tmp );
    }

    void swap( A &&a ) noexcept
    {
        int tmp = std::move( a.x );
        a.x = std::move( this->x );
        this->x = std::move( tmp );
    }


    const int & getX() const { return x; }
};

int main() 
{
    A a1( 10 );
    A a2( 20 );

    std::cout << "a1.x = " << a1.getX() << '\n';
    std::cout << "a2.x = " << a2.getX() << '\n';

    a1.swap( a2 );

    std::cout << "a1.x = " << a1.getX() << '\n';
    std::cout << "a2.x = " << a2.getX() << '\n';

    a1.swap( A( 30 ) );

    std::cout << "a1.x = " << a1.getX() << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
a1.x = 10
a2.x = 20
a1.x = 20
a2.x = 10
a1.x = 30
```

Comment: This looks like something along the lines of what I was looking for. I will get back to programming a bit later on today and get back to you, thanks.

Comment: By the way I have never seen explicit and noexcept used before. Are they necessary? I don't know if my examinator will allow me to use them.

Comment: @David Then exclude them.:)

Comment: Just wanted to let you know that it worked great, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can create a member function and call `std::swap` on your tree:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    void swapTrees(MyClass& other)
    {
        std::swap(tree, other.tree);
    }

private:
    Tree tree;    
};
```

Usage is

```
MyCalss a, b;
a.swapTrees(b);
```